# Retrieving Xml Attribute Value in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm new to C# & I'm trying to read XML attribute from XML file in my Asp.net web project, when i retrieve attribute content i get this result :
"System.XML.Attribute;"

here is XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

<!--creating XML file-->

<Document PagesInDocument="1" Filename="YahyaXML">
    <Page Filename="YahyaXML" ZonesInPage="1" PageID="0">
        <Zone TextLinesInZone="2" zoneLRY="558" zoneLRX="1202" 
            zoneULY="3" zoneULX="886" ZoneID="0">

            <TextLine Content="aaaaaaaaaaa" TextLineID="0"/>

            <TextLine Content="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" TextLineID="1"/>
        </Zone>
    </Page>
</Document>
```

Here is my c# code:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\NovoDynamics\NovoVerus\api\examples\C#Samples\WebAppTest\Uploads\test-ht.xml");
        StringBuilder Content_Value = new StringBuilder();


        XmlNodeList aNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Document/Page/Zone");

        XmlNodeList bNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Document/Page/Zone/TextLine");

        foreach (XmlNode aNode in aNodes)
        {
            XmlAttribute ULX_xml = aNode.Attributes["zoneULX"];
            XmlAttribute ULY_xml = aNode.Attributes["zoneULY"];
            XmlAttribute LRX_xml = aNode.Attributes["zoneLRX"];
            XmlAttribute LRY_xml = aNode.Attributes["zoneLRY"];

            if (ULX_xml.Value == TextBox5.Text &&  ULY_xml.Value == TextBox6.Text && LRX_xml.Value == TextBox7.Text && LRY_xml.Value == TextBox8.Text )
            {


            foreach (XmlNode bNode in bNodes)
            {
                //XmlAttribute ContentAttribute = bNode.Attributes["Content"];

                if (bNode.Attributes["Content"].Value != null)
                {
                    Content_Value.Append(bNode.Attributes["Content"].Value.ToString());


                }


            }

            Content_Value.Append("\n");

            }

        }


        TextBox9.Text = Content_Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Which attribute value do you need and how are you trying to retrieve it?

Comment: hi Sybren, im trying to retrieve TextLine content into a textbox controller

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. Try change first string in your xml file to:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

More: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256048(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            reader.ReadLine(); //skip identification

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            var results = doc.Descendants("Page").Select(x => new
            {
                filename = (string)x.Attribute("Filename"),
                page = (int)x.Attribute("ZonesInPage"),
                id = (int)x.Attribute("PageID"),
                zones = x.Elements("Zone").Select(y => new {
                    textLines = (int)y.Attribute("TextLinesInZone"),
                    ulx = (int)y.Attribute("zoneULX"),
                    uly = (int)y.Attribute("zoneULY"),
                    lrx = (int)y.Attribute("zoneLRX"),
                    lry = (int)y.Attribute("zoneLRY"),
                    textLine = y.Elements("TextLine").Select(z => new {
                        content = (string)z.Attribute("Content"),
                        id = (int)z.Attribute("TextLineID")
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```